# Converting data in JSON format to string format in python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have a IMDB dataset. It has a feature 'geners' which contains data in the form of JSON (i guess so) and to cary out further analysis, i need to convert that to string or any other format. How can i do that?

| gener | original_language |
| --- | --- |
| [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}] | en |

I need to deal with such data but I dont know how

i was expecting some usable output like storing the 'name' (from geners column) to some other column or anything that will be more usable than this format

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: JSON is a text format. `(i guess so` don't guess. Check the type and values of that column What you posted may be a JSON string, or it could be a list of dictionaries in a Pandas  dataframe. `df.gener.iloc[i].transpose()` would make that clear, as every field would appear in a separate line, and any text values (including JSON strings) would be quoted

Comment: The two answers show how to access the data if it's *not* a JSON string. You may have retrieved the API data in a way that already parsed the JSON strings into objects. Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

To convert the string inside column `gener` to a list and then convert it to columns you can use next example:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# apply literal_eval if necessary
df['gener'] = df['gener'].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode('gener')
df = pd.concat([df.pop('gener').apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('gener_'), df], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   gener_id gener_name original_language
0        35     Comedy                en
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the value of `gener` at column `i` just do this:
`df.gener.iloc[i][0]["name"]`.

In fact every single data entry in the `gener` column is a list with a single element (thus the index [0]) which is a dictionary containing the key `"name"` (thus the `['name']` to access its value) which I suppose is the value you need.

You can create a new columns to store the `names` of all `geners` if you want to keep the original column.
To do so:

`df['gener_name'] = df['gener'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['name'])`

You'll then have the following:

| gener | original_language | gener_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}] | en | Comedy |

This supposes that your data is stored in a dataframe called `df`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard json module, which is able to read the dictionary from the json format string

```py
import json

json_str = '''{
  "id": 35, "name": "Comedy"
}'''

print(json.dumps(json_str)) #> "{\n  \"id\": 35, \"name\": \"Comedy\"\n}"
print(json.loads(json_str)) #> {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}
```

there are also functions that read the dictionary from a file